# Align radio-buttons to center

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to align my radio-buttons and text to the centre but I can't get it to work, I want the radio-buttons to be in a straight line down and the text beside it, This is what it looks like right now, with HTML:
[image]

and the CSS is:

[image]

I hope you can help with this, because I've been struggling with this problem for hours.

Comment: remove `<br>` element from your html markup.

Comment: Try removing the class `checkboxes-div` from the block element `div` and let us know what you get?

Comment: That makes it go the the right of the other text that's not what i want, I want to center what I have @RaghavendraN

Comment: Try using `text-align: center` in `choose` class selector.

Comment: @LJ, That makes it like this http://prntscr.com/civpoh, I want the check boxes to be in a line down like i have drawn on the picture

Comment: I figured it out, after hours of trying, I added to the .checkboxes-div a padding-left:90px that seemed to put it what quites looks like the center :3 Thanks for your help guys i really appreciate you trying to help me!+
http://prntscr.com/civud0

Answer (score 0):

You should try using css tag float http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Sry, I dont comment but cannot, dont have repu

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<hr>
<div><label><input type="radio" /> Label text</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" /> Label text2</label></div>
```